# How do I schedule a job to run every 15 minutes on Mac OS Big Sur?

Tags: big-sur, cron, macos

I'm using Mac OS Big Sur.  I want to run a script every 15 minutes, so I added this using "crontab -e"

```
*/15 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'sh ~/Documents/my_script.sh'
```

However, upon saving the changes, I get this error

```
$ crontab -e
crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.4pWPga68Wc":6: bad day-of-week
crontab: errors in crontab file, can't install
```

What's the right way to schedule a job to run every 15 minutes on Mac OS Big Sur?

Comment: Did you refer to the documentation on how to structure a crontab entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re missing an asterisk

```
*/15 * * * *
```

Comment: @dave Also, if you `chmod +x ~/Documents/my_script.sh` you can shorten the command to `/bin/bash -l ~/Documents/my_script.sh`. If you don't need a login shell (which doesn't make a lot of sense for a cron job) you could also just use the script path/name.

Comment: That command line was an interesting mish-mash... forcing it into `bash`, forcing a login shell, then explicitly using `sh` to run it anyway.  Big Sur's `sh` is still `bash`, I think.